# Why probabilities are measured over intervals (instead of points) for continuous probability distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, random-variable, continuous-data

In case of discrete probability distributions, we find probabilities of different points/values over exactly those points, but in case of continuous probability distributions, we find probabilities of points within intervals --- why is that ?
Can we not find out probability of a continuous random variable at a given point without the interval?

Comment: We can -- but it is always zero.

Comment: @Nick So it approaches zero as the number of possible outcomes approaches infinity? It is 
not actually zero but is approaching zero ?

Comment: Probability zero is a subtle concept. The entire probability is always 1. How that can be reconciled with what I said requires some careful explanations.  I was sparse with a comment because I was trustful that someone would identify a duplicate.

Comment: depending on the power of a set a sum of zeros can be zero or more than zero